# Delete all my data from Realm after X hours?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, realm

I'm creating an iOS app with Swift (UIKit) where I'm storing all the data fetched from an API into a realm so it has offline usage. I was asked that the app must be usable in offline mode up to 24 hours from last opening it with an internet connection.

Is there a way to do this? I was thinking to start a timer for 24 hours when the user opens the app with internet connection (that re-starts everytime the user opens the app connected), and after the 24 hours are done, run a function to delete all the data from the realm.

Does this make sense?
Is there a better way to do it?

Thanks,

Comment: Why not just store the date/time the user last accessed the app with internet and compare that with the current time?

Comment: @Andrew - So that if the user opens the app again without connection compare both date/times (last date/time with connection and current date/time)? If the difference is bigger than 24hs delete all data and if it's lower show the data?

Comment: The question is a little vague; it asks about deleting data after x hours, but the body of the question says *I was asked that the app must be usable in offline mode up to 24 hours* which are two different questions. Realm data persists locally so once it's stored on the device it will be available for that 24 hours and thereafter. If you want to delete it, store that time on the device (perhaps in user defaults) and the next time the app starts compare the current time to the stored time and if it's > 24 hours, delete it. The data won't do anything or be active if the app isn't running.

Comment: Hi @Jay - Thank you, I might go with that approach. The reason I also included the X hours is for testing purposes mainly. In case I want to delete the data after 1 hour, instead of 24 hours, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anybody, I was able to do this by creating a new class to the realm (DateData), which I update every time the user opens the app and it's connected to Internet.

```
class DateData: Object {
 @objc dynamic var date: String = ""

 func dateToString(_ date : Date) -> String{
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let day = calendar.component(.day, from: date)
    let month = calendar.component(.month, from: date)
    let year = calendar.component(.year, from: date)
    let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: date)
    let minutes = calendar.component(.minute, from: date)
    let datetime = "\(day)/\(month)/\(year) \(hour):\(minutes)"
    
    return datetime
 }

 func stringToDate(_ date : String) -> Date{
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
    
    let newDate = formatter.date(from: date)
    return newDate!
 }
}
```

And add it to the realm with the following code:

```
let k = K()
if NetworkMonitor.shared.isConnected {
        print("Online mode")
        realmDB.deleteAllData()
        realmDB.addCurrentConnectionDateTime()
        // Code to execute when connected
    }else{
        print("Offline mode")
        let today = Date()
        let date = realmDB.getLastConnecionDate()
        print(today.timeIntervalSince(date))
        if today.timeIntervalSince(date) > (k.connectionHours * 3600) {
            realmDB.deleteAllData()
        }else{
            // Load data from Realm
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in my realm database I inserted the addCurrentConnectionDateTime() and getLastConnectionDate(). As well as the delete all data from realm:

```
struct RealmDatabase {

let realm = try! Realm()


//MARK: - Add current DateTime connection to Realm

func addCurrentConnectionDateTime(){
    let date = Date()
    let d: DateData = DateData()
    let dateString: String = d.dateToString(date)
    d.date = dateString
    // Update last connection with the new one
    try! realm.write{
        try! realm.delete(Realm().objects(DateData.self))
        realm.add(d)
    }
}

//MARK: - Get last connection DateTime
func getLastConnecionDate() -> Date {
    var newLastDate = Date()
    let lastDate = realm.objects(DateData.self)
    newLastDate = DateData().stringToDate(lastDate[0].date)
    
    return newLastDate
}

//MARK: - Delete all data from the Realm

func deleteAllData(){
    try! realm.write{
        try! realm.delete(Realm().objects(Movie.self))
        try! realm.delete(Realm().objects(Genre.self))
        try! realm.delete(Realm().objects(Review.self))
    }
}}
```

And that is it, now the value that you insert in the Constants file (K Struct), will be the amount of hours that the data will remain in the realm before being deleted.

There might be ways to better do this, as I'm pretty new with swift, but this works. I hope it helps anybody! Let me know.

Happy 2021!